# How to make username show up instead of "login" button if user logged in?

Tags: php, dom

I am a newbie in PHP and I would be glad if you'd help me.
I need "login" button on page to become "%username% (logout)" if the user is logged in. Also need to change href attribute of `<a>` to logout.php if logged in. The following code works but only if logged in

PHP:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
}
?>

<a id="login" href="login.php" style="color: #888888;font-size: 18px;">
            <?php
            echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);
            echo '(logout)';
            ?>
          </a>
```

Comment: @Mech if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])

Comment: It checks if logged in, but I don't know how to use this for my purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]){
// Show Login Button or Do Whatever
}else{
echo "$_SESSION["username"]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `<a>` tag text and href like this

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
    $href = 'login.php';
    $text = 'Login';
} else {
    $href = 'logout.php';
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]) . ' (Logout)';
}
?>

<a id="login" href="<?php echo $href; ?>" style="color: #888888;font-size: 18px;"><?php echo $text; ?></a>
```